# Getting JSP compile error when using GWT with Spring

Tags: spring, jsp, gwt

Has anyone come across such an error? This is happening because TagFileProcessor is getting picked up from gwt-dev.jar file instead of somewhere else. Putting GWT to the end of classpath does not help either. Google does not have anything for this error.

```
21:52:33,702 [DEBUG] JstlView:231 - Rendering view with name 'xyz/xyz' with model null and static attributes {}
ApplicationDispatcher[/]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.loadTagFile(TagFileProcessor.java:526)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.access$000(TagFileProcessor.java:47)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor$TagFileLoaderVisitor.visit(TagFileProcessor.java:565)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1441)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your application's libraries contain an old version of the JSP/Servlet API. This is tripping up Tomcat's JSP compiler.

One or more of the GWT JARs are guilty of this. You should not have `gwt-dev.jar` deployed with your application, `get-user.jar` is only used during GWT compilation and is therefore not required in the app either, and `gwt-servlet.jar` is only needed if you use GWT RPC.